# Fastest method to draw constructible regular polygons

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, polygons

We know from Gauss, that the regular polygons of order $3$, $4$, $5$, $6$, $8$, $10$, $12$, $15$, $16$, $17$, $20$, $24\ldots$ are constructible.

- Is there a provably fastest compass and straightedge method to create
  each (or some) of those polygons?
- If so, is the minimal number of steps (arcs and lines drawn) a known
  function of the number of sides?

For illustration purposes, an image of a construction of the 17-gon from Wikipedia, different from Gauss's original construction.

$\quad\quad\quad\quad$[image]

Comment: Just to clarify what's to be counted, starting with two points, you can get the third vertex of an equilateral triangle by drawing two circles, so is that a two-step construction?

Comment: @barrycipra : Yes, that counts as two steps: two arcs need to be drawn.

Comment: As the number of steps required to draw a polygon is a natural number, there is a minimum. For the triangle, $2$ is obviously the minimum as you need two lines to define the third vertex. Finding the minimum for the larger polygons seems to be an arduous endeavor.

Comment: @YvesDaoust - I was hoping someone would have tackled this problem since 1796....

Comment: When the number of sides is composite, the number of steps obviously exceeds those corresponding to the factors (the $12$-gon contains a square and a triangle). Conversely, I guess that a composite-gon can be contructed from the construction of the factor-gons plus a number of auxiliary constructs that does not exceed the number of sides.

Comment: This link (Constructibility of Regular Polygons) is quite instructive: http://www.google.be/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCYQFjABahUKEwiI4q-Zk-XHAhVGyRQKHawHACk&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.iastate.edu%2Fthesisarchive%2FMSM%2FEekhoffMSMSS07.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGjvHoz9ixWqu8BbyYsmlcON2U7ug&sig2=1aiVCwsfahltO6GYPiR2uQ&bvm=bv.102022582,d.d24

Comment: Here's another possibly instructive link:  https://books.google.com/books?id=_p3eBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA3&lpg=PA3&dq=coolidge+lemoine&source=bl&ots=BaVru03fh1&sig=KJMxqzOV_i-5T5TJeJRSOpdjg3E&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAWoVChMI8eqY3ZrlxwIVBHySCh1XTQlL#v=onepage&q=coolidge%20lemoine&f=false

Comment: Your diagram shows a variant of Richmond's construction. The tangent to $k_4$ where it intersects $OB$ is $P_5P_{12}$.

Answer (score 3):

Just to get the ball rolling, here is a five-step construction of a square starting from two points, which may or may not be minimal.  (In comments below the OP, I gave a two-step construction for the equilateral triangle, which I daresay cannot be constructed in a single step.)

Starting with points $P$ and $Q$,

1. Draw the circle centered at $P$ passing through $Q$.
2. Draw the circle centered at $Q$ passing through $P$.
   These two circles intersect at two points $R$ and $S$.
3. Draw the line through $P$ and $Q$.
4. Draw the line through $R$ and $S$.  These two lines are perpendicular, intersecting at a point $O$.
5. Draw a circle of arbitrary radius centered at $O$.  Its intersections with the lines of Steps 3 and 4 are vertices of a square.

What's lacking here, of course, is proof that five is minimal.  I hope someone will post an answer giving such a proof (or, better yet, a construction that takes fewer steps.)

**Added later**:  Just to keep the ball rolling (and/or consume some additional low-hanging fruit), here's a four-step construction for the hexagon:

Starting with points $O$ and $P$,

1. Draw the circle centered at $O$ passing through $P$.
2. Draw the circle centered at $P$ passing through $O$. These two circles intersect at two points $A$ and $D$.
3. Draw the line through $O$ and $P$. It intersects the circle from Step 1 at a point $Q$.
4. Draw the circle centered at $Q$ passing through $O$. It intersects the circle from Step 1 at two points $B$ and $C$.  The points $P,A,B,Q,C,D$ are vertices of a hexagon.

I think this is "obviously" minimal.  But I think we need some explicit rules for what constitutes a construction in order to prove it's obvious....

Comment: That's a good start :)

Comment: $3$ is a lower bound. Indeed, two lines intersect in a single point, and a line and a circle intersect in at most two points. Hence it takes at least three steps to get the four vertices.

Comment: If you start from two given points $P_0$ and $P_1$ and are only allowed to - draw a line through two known points - draw a circle centered on a known point and through another known point, $4$ is a lower bound. Indeed, you can draw $L_{01}$ and $C_{01}$ (or $C_{10}$), giving you $P_2$. Then you have no other choice than $C_{02}$ (or $C_{20}$), creating $P_3$ and $P_4$. Among those 5 points, no square. Alternatively, you can start with $C_{01}$ and $C_{10}$, creating $P_2$ and $P_3$. Drawing a line or a circle will not create a square, and you need at least one more construct.

Comment: By a similar argument, none of 1 line + 2 circles or 3 circles define an hexagon (the other combinations do not exist).

Comment: @YvesDaoust, I think your comments would be worth writing up as a separate answer.

Comment: I will consider it but need some time to put order into that.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:

If you start from two given points and only allow to draw a straight line from two known points or a circle centered on one known point and through another, you can sketch all the possible constructions.

With a single line:

[image]

With two lines (you get the equilateral triangle):

[image]

With three lines:

[image]

With four lines (you get the hexagon):

[image]

The fifth construction with four lines shows you how to achieve the square in five lines (with an extra circle).

I conjecture that allowing to draw through unknown points would not reduce the minimum number of lines. Unfortunately, this brute force approach very quickly becomes impractical.

---

**Update**:

There is a missing operation: measure the distance between two known points with the compass and draw a circle with this radius around a third point.

Also, many constructions with larger circles are missing.

Comment: Now the challenge:  Prove the minimal construction of a pentagon :)

Comment: @nbubis: Another line of attack is to compute the angles that can be constructed.

Comment: For a pentagon, you need to somehow construct an angle of $72°$. The cosine of this angle is $(\sqrt5-1)/4$. The $\sqrt5$ is obtained by Pythagoras, from a triangle of sides $1$ and $2$. From there, the required cosine and corresponding angle are easy. I guess that these operations are key to finding the minimum number of lines.

Comment: The second construction at http://www.geocities.ws/robinhuiscool/Pentagon.html produces a regular pentagon in $8$ steps.

Comment: @BarryCipra: I confirm the count $8$.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add a simple observation (not an answer):

Since circles can intersect twice, whereas lines can intersect once or twice, the maximal number of intersections is given by twice the number of pairs of circles. Moreover, for a $n$-gon, clearly at least $n$ intersections are needed. Thus, a very loose lower bound is given by:
$$C^2-C > n$$ 
Which would mean the number of steps is asymptomatically bound from below by $O\left(\sqrt{n}\right)$.

Comment: If we require all intersections to be made with the same circumcircle, we need at least $\lceil n/2\rceil$ other lines !?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Only $\left\lfloor n/2\right\rfloor$ if one vertex is given or if we may choose any point for the first vertex without drawing any lines. So, for example, if $n=5$, two circles would do; if $n=17$, eight.

Answer (score 1):

Just to keep the ball rolling, here is a quick way to draw the regular pentagon.

Start with a circle, centre $O$, and draw two mutually perpendicular diameters $AB$ and $CD$.

Find the midpoint of $OD$ and call it $E$.

Draw the line $BE$ extended, and bisect the angle $BEO$ both internally and externally.

These bisectors meet $AB$ at $X$ and $Y$. Construct lines perpendicular to $AB$ through $X$ and $Y$.

These perpendicular meet the circle at four points, which, together with $B$, form a regular pentagon.

I'm not sure how many steps this is according to your rules, but I would be interested to know if there is a quicker way. I doubt it.

Comment: Finding the midpoint is not an atomic operation unfortunately, nor is angle bisection.

Comment: @nbubis.What do you mean by atomic? Each operation is a given number of arcs and lines....

Comment: To get the mid point of a line you need to draw at least three additional lines.

Comment: Two arcs and one straight line is sufficient

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the task is to inscribe a regular $n$-gon in a given circle. Once vertices $P_0$ and $P_i$ are located, where $i$ is coprime to $n$, the others may be found easily. It takes $O(n)$ steps to construct them, so this part of the task is more expensive, the greater $n$ is.

However, if we concentrate on that part of the task which is the location of $P_i$, this might not be harder for $n=2k$ or $n=4k$ than it is for $n=k$. Consider, for example, $n=5$ and $n=10$. Denote the pentagon's vertices by $P_i$ and the decagon's by $D_i$. Where the circumradius is $1$, the pentagon's side and diagonal $P_0P_2$ are $\sqrt{\dfrac{5\mp\sqrt5}2}$. The decagon's side and diagonal $D_0D_3$ are $\dfrac{\sqrt5\mp1}2$. The decagon's vertices $D_1, D_9$ may be found from $D_0$ thus:
[image: Inscribing a regular decagon in a given circle]

Call the given circle $\Omega_1$. Draw $\Omega_1$'s diameter $D_0OD_5$. Construct radius $OB\perp OD_0$. Bisect $OB$ at $C$. Draw $D_0C$. Draw a circle with centre $C$ through $O$, cutting $D_0C$ at $D$. Draw a circle  with centre $D_0$ through $D$, cutting $\Omega_1$ at $D_1$ and $D_9$.

To get this far entails constructing 7 circles (3 to construct a perpendicular, 2 to bisect a line segment, and 2 more). This is the same as for Ptolemy's method to inscribe a regular pentagon. Indeed a regular pentagon can be inscribed using a method similar to the above for the decagon: draw $CD_5$ instead of $CD_0$, thus locating $D_4, D_6$, which are $P_2, P_3$ where $D_0$ is $P_0$. And since perpendicular radii have been constructed, the $20$-gon follows just as easily.

Inscribing a regular $17$-gon in a given circle also entails constructing perpendicular radii, one of them through the given vertex. Thus the $34$-gon and $68$-gon follow just as easily.

Comment: Thanks! That's an important optimization, though still really far from an answer to the problem. It's amazing how seemingly simple question can be so hard to answer.