# Optimal Compass and Straightedge Constructions

Tags: geometry, optimization, euclidean-geometry, computational-complexity, geometric-construction

I was recently looking over some Islamic geometry patterns, and was struck by the complexity of the constructions needed to create seemingly simple patterns. This got me wondering regarding optimal compass and straightedge constructions. To better define the question:

One is given some initial collection of constructed points, and a new (constructable) point to be constructed.

1. Are there known methods for finding the optimal construction (minimum needed number of arcs and lines)?
2. If there isn't, are there any methods for reducing the search space, e.g. for computer assisted searches?
3. Is there a known method for checking if a given solution is optimal?

Comment: For 1. a BFS could theoretically be used to find all optima, but doing so might be impractical for more than a handful of steps.

Comment: @MvG - Hence part two of the question.

Comment: So apparently I already asked a subset of this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1425092/fastest-method-to-draw-constructible-regular-polygons?rq=1

And never got a complete answer. I'm guessing this problem is unsolved?

Comment: I added the relevant tag and asked [Alexander Wolff](http://www1.informatik.uni-wuerzburg.de/en/staff/wolff-alexander) whether he heard about this problem.  If no then it may be a good and natural open problem topic for our research.

Comment: The creators of the app Euclidea (https://www.euclidea.xyz/) seem to have answered this question at least in part; you win levels by constructing given things using compass and straightedge, and it algorithmically determines whether you've done it. Since the space of constructions using just a few moves isn't all that big, I suspect this sort of thing could be used in the 'forward' direction in addition to the 'backward' direction of checking constructions.

Comment: @AlexRavsky - Come up with anything?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.